# UITableView reloadData asynchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I'm making a search function for my application that I want to highlight the search string in the cell.
To do this, I save the search string to a global variable `activeSearchString` that can be accessed by `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` then highlights the content of `activeSearchString` in the cell it will return.
However, it isn't working. If you check the log, it seems like reloadData is performed asynchronous (so after `activeSearchString` has been deallocated).
Because of this, my app also crashes.. Any solution to perform `reloadData`synchronous or another approach? Thanks!

Code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(){
    // Get the products asynchronous    
    NSString* searchString = [NSString stringWithString:@"A search string"];
    NSArray* searchResults = [[ProductServer sharedServer] productsForSearchString:searchString];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
        DLog(@"Begin");
        activeSearchString = [searchString retain];
        products = [searchResults retain];
        [ibTableView reloadData];
        [activeSearchString release];
        DLog(@"End");
    });
});

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        DLog();
        ProductTableViewCell* tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"productCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        Product* product = [products objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        NSDictionary* highlightAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:49.f/255.f green:110.f/255.f blue:184.f/255.f alpha:1.f], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, nil];
        NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttributedTitle = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[product title]] autorelease];
        [mutableAttributedTitle setAttributes:highlightAttributes range:[[mutableAttributedTitle string] rangeOfString:activeSearchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch]];
        [(UILabel*)[tableViewCell titleLabel] setAttributedText:mutableAttributedTitle];

        return tableViewCell;
}
```

Log:

```
2012-11-13 14:56:00.783 ****[5810:c07] __58-[TVCurrentlyViewController searchBarSearchButtonClicked:]_block_invoke_2 [Line 190] Begin
2012-11-13 14:56:00.783 ****[5810:c07] __58-[TVCurrentlyViewController searchBarSearchButtonClicked:]_block_invoke_2 [Line 197] End
2012-11-13 14:56:00.783 ****[5810:c07] -[TVCurrentlyViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 117] 
2012-11-13 14:56:00.786 ****[5810:c07] -[TVCurrentlyViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 117] 
2012-11-13 14:56:00.787 ****[5810:c07] -[TVCurrentlyViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 117] 
2012-11-13 14:56:00.789 ****[5810:c07] -[TVCurrentlyViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] [Line 117] 
2012-11-13 14:56:00.790 ****[5810:c07] *** -[CFString length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x75d6d00
```

Comment: Add the code for your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be releasing a global there. Use a synthesized property with retain semantics and release in the view controller's dealloc method.

Edit:

Use `dispatch_async()` instead of `dispatch_sync()` in your call back to the main thread. `dispatch_sync()` will block the global background queue while the main thread finishes updating the tableview.